# He activado MAMP en mi MacBook. ¿Cómo puedo visualizar mi index.php de mi proyecto en el navegador (Chrome u otro)?

Tags: php, localhost, macos

He activado MAMP en mi MacBook. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo visualizar mi index.php de mi proyecto en el navegador (Chrome u otro)?

Puse todos los archivos de mi proyecto dentro de 'MAMP / htdocs'. Ahora, en "http: // localhost: 8888 / MyProject" aparece un error 500

Answer (score 0):

¡HECHO! He instalado el composer. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md), y eso es todo.

¡Gracias Mauricio!